# Can anyone identify this plant, possibly a salad leaf?

Tags: identification, leaves, edible

I was given some seeds that I was told were [pak choi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bok_choy). However the plants growing from these don't look anything like pak choi to me.

It's possible the seeds got mixed up with other salad varieties they were giving out - is anyone able to identify what the plant is from this photo?

[image: unidentified leaf]

I can supply further photos of different parts if needed.

Comment: My best guess is that this is something in the mustard family. I have grown plants similar to this from seeds a friend brought from Southeast Asia. They were presented to me as bak choi, but I think that is only because bak choi is widely known in the West.

Comment: Can you break one leaf, and report on the odor?

Comment: Yes good idea. Nothing remarkable to report - it just smells a bit like grass, or rocket but less peppery. It smells like a generic salad leaf!

Comment: So not astringent/pungent, or mustardy... are the pubescent at all, on either leaf side, or are they completely smooth?

Comment: @J.Musser How do you describe mustardy? I've had Mizuna before and it seemed pretty generic to me, notwithstanding it's basically a variety of mustard greens. Maybe I just need to eat it more, though.

Comment: @J. Musser the leaves and stems are completely smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks quite a bit like Persian Cress. (Lepidium Sativum) I have a Jhonnys seed catalog and its pretty much the only green that looks like that leaf type, pretty distinctive serrated edge and oval shape. The bright true green color is right on too. Catalog says the flavor is mild. 21 days to maturity at 2-6" long. Yum.